# Paired Bluetooth - Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, ios-bluetooth

I know about Swift restrictions concerning non BLE devices.

This is my issue: I'd like my app to detect car stereo which is ALREADY (manually) paired with my iPhone. I'm trying to use the External Accessory framework, but sadly, despite my iPhone is paired and connected to the car stereo while testing, the following code (triggered by tapping a button) doesn't show any bluetooth device connected to the phone:

```
@IBAction func seekPC(_ sender: Any) {
        //(PairedConnected -- PC)
        accessories = [EAAccessory]()
        for accessory in eaManager.connectedAccessories {
            print("got one") //this is never printed!
            accessories.append(accessory)
        }
        table.reloadData()
    }
```

Obviously there's a table view which should display the accessories that are connected to my phone, but as I said earlier no devices are found. 
Some help would be appreciated!

Comment: External accessory framework is only for MFi devices. A standard device such as a car stereo won't show up.

Comment: Thanks @Paulw11, would you suggest me to use the AV framework to detect the car stereo bluetooth connected to my phone?

Comment: You can detect available audio routes via the av framework but it doesn't really tell you anything about the connected device.

Comment: @Paulw11 I didn't know the fact that a car stereo was undetectable through External Accessory framework. Without your answer I think I would have kept using EA with no results: big thanks!

Comment: @Daniel993 did you find a suitable solution connection to your device?

Comment: @Maurice Yes, I ended up using AVFoundation.. The AVAudioSession object offers the field availableInputs which is able to show non LE bluetooth devices

Comment: @Daniel993 clever. Do you have a reference or working example?